# Javascript epoch in c#

Tags: c#, javascript

I search the forum for my problem but found nothing. :(
This DateTime conversion drives me mad.

I try to convert a millisecond epoch to DateTime.
I found this Methode in the Internet:

```
    private DateTime TimeFromUnixTimestamp(int unixTimestamp)
    {
        DateTime unixYear0 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        long unixTimeStampInTicks = unixTimestamp * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
        DateTime dtUnix = new DateTime(unixYear0.Ticks + unixTimeStampInTicks);
        return dtUnix;
    }

    private DateTime TimeFromJavaTimestamp(long javaTimestamp)
    {
        return TimeFromUnixTimestamp((int)(javaTimestamp / 1000));
    }
```

Now to test the method I run this code in JavaScript:

```
    Date.UTC(2014,05,06,0,0,0,0);
```

[You can test it here (jsfiddler)](http://jsfiddle.net/sWLR3/)

The result is **1402012800000**.
So far so good. Now I test my c# methode:

```
    var test = TimeFromJavaTimestamp(1402012800000L);
```

and as result I get **{06.06.2014 00:00:00}**!
One month offset to what I do expected??

Can somebody explain this to me???

Regards Steffen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

> month An integer between 0 and 11 representing the month.

So, yeah, the month 05 is June. Looks like your code is working.

Comment: Yea, JavaScript uses array indices for months for some bizarre reason. I know about the issue and I still mess it up so often that I avoid the native `Date` object in favor of a library whenever I need more than a timestamp.

Comment: Yep, Year is 1 based, day is 1 based, but month is ZERO based. Go home JavaScript, you're drunk!

Comment: Damn you JavaScript!! I know this but forget about it... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

In JavaScript:

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
```

Then in C# to convert a JavaScript timestamp to a DateTime object:

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(long timestamp)
{
    var dateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp / 1000).ToLocalTime();
}
```